# 'Warning', '1265', 'Data truncated for column \'arrival_date\' at row 1' - Not sure why this is being triggered

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to import data from a .txt file into my database, but for some reason every time it tries to import the arrival date I get the warning 1265 and the import fails.

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
order_id int(9) PRIMARY KEY,
line_num int(1),
vendor_id int(9),
product_id int(9),
product_price decimal(9,2),
order_quantity decimal(9,2),
order_date date,
arrival_date date,
FOREIGN KEY (vendor_id) REFERENCES VENDOR(vendor_id),
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES PRODUCT(product_id)
)ENGINE=innodb;
```

This is my import statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\admin\\Desktop\\imports\\Orders.txt' INTO TABLE ORDERS
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\r\\n';
```

This is an example of the data I'm trying to import:

```
10001   1   1001    1122    4.25    19500.00    2017-11-03  2017-11-23
10002   1   1005    1243    4.25    10000.00    2017-11-06  2017-11-24
10003   1   1004    5462    1.05    23000.00    2017-11-08  2017-11-25
```

Yet everytime I run the import, I get

```
"'Warning', '1265', 'Data truncated for column \'arrival_date\' at row 1'".
```

I don't know what's wrong with my arrival_date (the last column) that is throwing this error.

Comment: Show us an example of your data. It looks like your dates are enclosed incorrecly with `"` or `'`

Comment: @AndrewShmig there is an example in the OP, but here is a larger example set:

https://i.imgur.com/9j9Qp5U.png

Comment: Are you sure you have `\t` delimiter between two dates? Looks like there is a space, not a tab.

Comment: Yes @AndrewShmig In Notepad++ a space shows simply as a space, a tab will show that orange arrow symbol. I've gone back and double checked this, despite the spacing being small, it is indeed a tab.

Comment: What is the latest row you successfully insert and than mysql shows warning? You should double check your dates... even by changing data type in your table (`date` to `text`). If this will work - search for an incorrect dates.

Comment: I've figured it out, it was just a dumb error. In my import I had Lines terminated by '\\r\\n'. It should have been Lines terminated by '\r\n'.

Comment: Off topic: You know `line_num int(1)` doesn't hold one digit right?  in fact `int([number])` is pretty meaningless unless you are using column option zerofull

Comment: @B.Vee, you should post this comment as an answer and accept it after 24 hours.